# Object Decomposition on Extended Types

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces as follows:

```
interface A{
   ...
}
interface B extends A{
   ...
   newKey: val
}
```

Consider I have object `B_i`, which is of instance `B`

```
const {newKey, A_i} = B_i
```

While A_i is typed, it is not specifically of interface A. Other than setting a new variable and typing that, like so,

```
const A_i2: A = A_i
```

is there some way to type `A_i`?

Comment: Right now I pull an object from a database, but because it needs to be JSON serializable, there is a conversion that needs to be made before it is sent to the rest of the application.